# Display UTC time incorrect after 12am

Tags: javascript

I'm using a simple javascript to display the local time in my country on a website, but it seems to be broken. After 12 midnight, by right the clock should reset to AM instead, but it keeps showing the time in PM (eg. 1 PM instead of 1 AM)

Body:

```
<body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )">

//div tags, elements etc

</body>
```

JS:

```
function updateClock (){

var currentTime =  new Date();
var currentHours = currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8; 
var currentMinutes = currentTime.getUTCMinutes();
var currentSeconds = currentTime.getUTCSeconds();

// var bucurestiOffset = 3*60000;
// var userOffset = currentTime.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;

currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
  document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}
```

Result: 13:52:40 PM. Current time where im located is 1:52 AM.
Don't know how to go about fixing this.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://momentjs.com/

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: `currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8` can't be right, can it? It moves the hour from the [0, 23] range to [8, 21]...

Comment: Also, why on earth are you using the `getUTCWhatever` methods and perfoming TZ correction manually instead of simply using `getWhatever`?

Comment: Im displaying the time in my Region. Hence the use of UTC.

Answer (score 0):

If you simple display UTC time use ;

```
new Date().toJSON()
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
var currentHours = currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8;
```

to this

**EDIT:**

```
var currentHours = (currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8) % 24;
```

When the UTC time in hours becomes lets say 19 hours, then your `currentHours` variable becomes 27 hours instead of 3 hours which is why the problem occurs. "Moddin" it solves the problem.

Comment: Hi, the solution doesnt seem to work. Also, I have added the javascrip invoke code that was declared in the body tag in the question.

Comment: I think you mean `(var currentHours = currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8) % 24;`

Comment: I doubt that'd work, because If im not mistaken you cant declare a variable inside of a bracket?

Comment: T think I added the remainder operator in the wrong place. I guess it should be `var currentHours = (currentTime.getUTCHours() + 8) % 24;`

Comment: And sorry for the inconvenience please check the edited answer.